# Unable to write Windows 10 ISO file to a standard DVD because it is too large

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, dvd, iso-image, burning

I am trying to burn the ISO image file that the Windows 10 Media Creation Tool generated onto a standard DVD-R disc. The problem is that the ISO is about 150 MB too big for the disc I am using. I have tried using Nero 12, IMGBurn, and the built-in Windows ISO burning tool on my Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit main machine and the same problem occurs with each. I have an LG WH16NS40 Blu-ray/DVD/CD burner/rewriter. I have tried multiple blank discs and none of them work. I really do not want to waste a blank Blu-ray on this, nor do I want to have to dedicate an expensive flash drive to it. Has anyone else solved this issue?

Comment: The file size is variable, depending on which options you select, somewhere between 3 & 6GB. It's always been recommended to use a USB key - dirt cheap these days... & re-useable.

Comment: I really don't want to waste a flash drive on this.  I wouldn't trust those cheap generic ones for an OS boot disk, and I am not paying $10 or more for a good one, just bootable OS install media.

Comment: 'Waste' seems a peculiar word to use for a device that's eminently re-usable... if you really want to do it on DVD, then you need double density

Comment: Restrict yourself to a single architecture (*either* x86 *or* x64) and it'll fit. Official ISOs (not what the tool creates) are always single-architecture.

Comment: Any idea where I could find an ISO of just 64Bit pro?  A legal one that is.

Comment: As Daniel B already implied, utilize the `Windows 10 Media Creation Tool` and select just the 64-bit version:  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKzBn.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKzBn.png).  Windows 10 Pro will be included, an it will fit on one DVD:  [How to Download a Windows 10 ISO File](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/9230-windows-10-iso-download.html).

Comment: There is a method to do this by extracting the desired WIM from the ISO manually, compressing it, and then creating a new ISO with the updated WIM file, but I'm waiting for 1903 to officially release to verify that it still works. Assuming it releases on Tuesday as rumors are claiming, I should have a full write-up posted within a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I have succeeded in making a Windows 10 iso that will fit into a 4.7 GB DVD, here's what I did:

Download and install NTLite https://www.ntlite.com

Extract Windows iso using 7-zip for example

In NTLite, add image directory

Delete all editions except the one you need

Right click on "operating systems | install.wim" then choose convert -> ESD

Create ISO